# Simple XML Reader: Não consigo converter nodes em HTML e nem limitar o número de itens

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, xml-schema, simplexml

Tenho utilizado o [SimpleXMLReader](https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader)
para fazer parse de uma estrutura XML gigantesca, que possui mais de 25mb.

Meu código funciona normalmente, porém, estou com dois problemas:

1. Não consigo transformar o `Xpath` em `HTML`. Bom, eu dei uma estudada nisso, e vi que não é uma tarefa fácil, é possível mesmo fazer isso? Acontece que o Xpath não permite que eu utilize os valores dentro de uma string PHP no código HTML.
2. Não consigo limitar a quantidade de itens exibidos. Eu já olhei todo o código do arquivo simpleXMLreader.php, mas não vejo nenhum meio de limitar a quantidade de itens extraídos do XML, me disseram para utilizar `foreach` junto ao `Xpath`no código principal, eu tentei, mas não funcionou.

Baixe o software SimpleXMLReader aqui: `https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader`

Meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Boutique</title>

 </head>
  <body>



<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/va/artigos-complexos/afilio/afilio-vitrine.css" type="text/css" />

<div class="mainproductebayfloatright-bottom">


<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__). "/simplexmlreader.php";
class ExampleXmlReader1 extends SimpleXMLReader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // by node name
        $this->registerCallback("nome", array($this, "callbackNome"));
        $this->registerCallback("preco_promocao", array($this, "callbackPrice"));

    }
    protected function callbackNome($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $name = $xml;
        $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
        echo "$xpath: Nome = $name;\n";
        return true;
    }


     protected function callbackPrice($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $preco_promocao = $xml;
        $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
        echo "$xpath: Preço = $preco_promocao;\n";
        return true;
    }



}
echo "<pre>";


?>
 <div class="aroundebay">
        <div id="aroundebay2">


<?php
        print "<div class=\"titleebay\"><a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"$link_produto\">" . $title . "</a></div>";
        print "<div class=\"mainproduct\"><a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"$link\"><img style=\"height:120px\" src=\"$imagem\"/><br/>";

    //print "De:;&nbspR$". $preco_normal . "<br/>";
    print "<span>Apenas&nbspR$" . $preco_promocao . "<br/></a></span></div>";
    //print "Em&nbsp" . $parcelas . "x de&nbsp:&nbspR$" . $vl_parcelas . "</a></span></div>";






    ?>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>
<?php

//Pega o arquivo pelo caminho relativo
//$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/boutique.xml";
$reader = new ExampleXmlReader1;
// Pega o arquivo pela URL. Original: $reader->open($file);
$reader->open("http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML"); 
$reader->parse();
$reader->close();
?>




 </body>
</html>
```

PS: O CSS não é relevante.

Answer (score 4):

A solução pode ser usando simple xml, que já vem com o PHP?

O segredo é usar o método [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) do XPATH para filtrar os registros que você quer.

```
function parse($url, $offset = 1, $limit = -1)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $limitCriteria = '';

    if ($limit > 0) {
        $limitCriteria = 'and position() <= ' . ((int)$offset + (int)$limit + 1);
    }

    $products = array();

    $path = sprintf('//produto[position() >= %s %s]', (int)$offset, $limitCriteria);

    foreach($xml->xpath($path) as $product) {
        $products[] = array(
          'nome' => $product->nome,
          'preco_promocao' =>  $product->preco_promocao,
        );
    }

    return $products;
}


$products = parse('boutique.xml', 10, 10);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product['nome'] . ' ' . $product['preco_promocao'] . "\n";
}
?>
```

O output desse cara em cima do xml da url que você passou é:

```
DVD Matrix Reloaded 14.99
DVD - Antes do Amanhecer 19.99
DVD O Gênio da Tesoura 19.99
CD Roberto Carlos - Ao Vivo (1988) 21.99
CD Roberto Carlos - Detalhes - 1971 21.99
CD Fagner Ao Vivo - Vol. 2 17.99
CD Jota Quest - Oxigênio 17.99
Barraca para 3 Pessoas Cherokee 3 - Nautika 469.99
Edredom Solteiro 156x230 100% Plumas de Ganso - Daune 546.99
Edredom Casal 220x240 100% Plumas de Ganso - Daune 649.99
Edredom Queen 240x260 100% Plumas de Ganso - Daune 734.99
CD ROM DOCUMENTS TO GO 1.49
```

Comment: Mas isso funciona bem com o arquivo gigante?

Comment: O arquivo que eu baixei, do link do seu código, esta com 66 MB. Ele demorou 1.5 segundos pra processar todo o arquivo no meu notebook.

Comment: Certo, e quanto a parte do HTML? Essa sua solução é um código completamente novo ou é um implemento?

Comment: Agora basta você colocar o seu HTML dentro do foreach, uma tabela, uma lista, ae vai de como você quer mostrar os dados.  Não entendi a pergunta sobre o código.

Comment: Cara, eu não estou conseguindo.

Comment: O que voce ainda nao consegue? Onde esta empacando?

Comment: Vc desenvolveu uma solução aí em cima, eu tentei jogá-la dentro do meu codigo e nao deu certo. Ou essa solução que vc desenvolveu é pra ser usada separadamente?

Comment: Já entendi como funciona seu código. Mas será que você consegue colocá-lo pra funcionar com este XML `http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML`?

Comment: Teste com o arquivo local e com a URL, aí vc vai ver pq eu disse q o negócio pesa muito.

Answer (score 0):

Já marquei a melhor resposta para a pergunta, mas seria realmente bom se alguém pudesse responder a minha pergunta específica. O rapaz ali me deu uma resposta que resolveu meu problema, mas foi utilizando uma alternativa sem o Simple XML Reader.